# framework for CGRectIntersectsRect function

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

Hi I am writing a game with cocos2d and using the ipad 5.0 simulator. at compiling I am getting this link error which says the CGRectIntersectsRect symbol is not found for architecture i386.  I think I am missing the right framework to get rid of this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> I think I am missing the right framework

Right, the framework you'll want to link against is CoreGraphics.

Note that you must also correctly

```
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
```

in order inline functions to work/be compiled properly.

Comment: @Mithelee In this case, are you sure you're importing `<CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>` correctly? This function might be inline, so if it is, and the header is not imported, then the compiler assumes it to be an normal function returning `int` and it will act as if wasn't inline. But since it's inline, the framework executable doesn't contain it, hence the linker error.

Comment: so in my code I have imported <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h> but still getting the error.

Comment: @Mithelee that's practically impossible. You're missing something else as well. Using Xcode? Try cleaning the project.

Comment: ok problem solved. it's actually defined in CGGeometry.h.  Thank you though H2CO3